# Building SQL query in XML with a CDATA select

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, cdata

I have a very silly problem using an xml based tool to extract data from an oracle database;

The datasource contains records with only one double quote, which is not handled in the code of the tool, and makes it crash. I can't change the source code of the tool, and I can't change the data source.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I could build up a query that would output something (unique and recognizable) where the data source contains double quotes? Keep in mind please I have to build the query as one xml string.

So far I've tried using cdata, like this;

```
SQLSelect="select '<![CDATA['||column_name||']]>' from table_name"
```

The SQL select itself works fine in oracle, but it breaks my XML. Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 select REPLACE ( column_name, '"', '&quot;' ) from table_name
```

Comment: Thanks :) That solves it. Had no idea you could do that in a select!